# Requested URL not found when file not in URL

Tags: apache-2.2

Sorry for the poor title wording. I just configured an Apache web server and uploaded my site's files to the proper directory. When a page is included in the URL, such as `IP/index.php`, the page loads properly, but when I type just the IP or domain name I get the following message:

```
The requested URL /.php was not found on this server.
```

What have I possibly done wrong?

I have specified the `DirectoryIndex index.php` in both `httpd.conf` and `.htaccess`.

I am running CentOS 6.6 and Apache 2.2.

Comment: Where is your configuration? Where is your error log entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I had AllowOverride set to None for what directives can be placed in the `.htaccess` file.

```
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
    AllowOverride All
```

Which is odd because I had other lines in the .htaccess file that allowed the file extension to be removed and that worked fine.